# Understanding Numba Performance Differences

Tags: numpy, numba

I'm trying to understand the performance differences I am seeing by using various `numba` implementations of an algorithm. In particular, I would expect `func1d` from below to be the fastest implementation since it it the only algorithm that is not copying data, however from my timings `func1b` appears to be fastest.

```py
import numpy
import numba


def func1a(data, a, b, c):
    # pure numpy
    return a * (1 + numpy.tanh((data / b) - c))


@numba.njit(fastmath=True)
def func1b(data, a, b, c):
    new_data = a * (1 + numpy.tanh((data / b) - c))
    return new_data


@numba.njit(fastmath=True)
def func1c(data, a, b, c):
    new_data = numpy.empty(data.shape)
    for i in range(new_data.shape[0]):
        for j in range(new_data.shape[1]):
            new_data[i, j] = a * (1 + numpy.tanh((data[i, j] / b) - c)) 
    return new_data


@numba.njit(fastmath=True)
def func1d(data, a, b, c):
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        for j in range(data.shape[1]):
            data[i, j] = a * (1 + numpy.tanh((data[i, j] / b) - c)) 
    return data
```

Helper functions for testing memory copying

```py
def get_data_base(arr):
    """For a given NumPy array, find the base array
    that owns the actual data.
    
    https://ipython-books.github.io/45-understanding-the-internals-of-numpy-to-avoid-unnecessary-array-copying/
    """
    base = arr
    while isinstance(base.base, numpy.ndarray):
        base = base.base
    return base


def arrays_share_data(x, y):
    return get_data_base(x) is get_data_base(y)


def test_share(func):
    data = data = numpy.random.randn(100, 3)
    print(arrays_share_data(data, func(data, 0.5, 2.5, 2.5)))
```

Timings

```
# force compiling
data = numpy.random.randn(10_000, 300)
_ = func1a(data, 0.5, 2.5, 2.5)
_ = func1b(data, 0.5, 2.5, 2.5)
_ = func1c(data, 0.5, 2.5, 2.5)
_ = func1d(data, 0.5, 2.5, 2.5)

data = numpy.random.randn(10_000, 300)
%timeit func1a(data, 0.5, 2.5, 2.5)
%timeit func1b(data, 0.5, 2.5, 2.5)
%timeit func1c(data, 0.5, 2.5, 2.5)
%timeit func1d(data, 0.5, 2.5, 2.5)
```

```
67.2 ms ± 230 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
13 ms ± 10.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
69.8 ms ± 60.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
69.8 ms ± 105 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Test which implementations copy memory

```py
test_share(func1a)
test_share(func1b)
test_share(func1c)
test_share(func1d)
```

```
False
False
False
True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, copying of data doesn't play a big role: the bottle neck is fast how the `tanh`-function is evaluated. There are many algorithms: some of them are faster some of them are slower, some are more precise some less.

Different numpy-distributions use different implementations of `tanh`-function, e.g. it could be one from mkl/vml or the one from the gnu-math-library.

Depending on numba version, also either the mkl/svml impelementation is used or gnu-math-library.

The easiest way to look inside is to use a profiler, for example `perf`.

For the numpy-version on my machine I get:

```
>>> perf record python run.py
>>> perf report
Overhead  Command  Shared Object                                      Symbol                                  
  46,73%  python   libm-2.23.so                                       [.] __expm1
  24,24%  python   libm-2.23.so                                       [.] __tanh
   4,89%  python   _multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  [.] sse2_binary_scalar2_divide_DOUBLE
   3,59%  python   [unknown]                                          [k] 0xffffffff8140290c
```

As one can see, numpy uses the slow gnu-math-library (`libm`) functionality.

For the numba-function I get:

```
 53,98%  python   libsvml.so                                         [.] __svml_tanh4_e9
   3,60%  python   [unknown]                                          [k] 0xffffffff81831c57
   2,79%  python   python3.7                                          [.] _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
```

which means that fast mkl/svml functionality is used.

That is (almost) all there is to it.

---

As @user2640045 has rightly [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70428347/5769463), the numpy performance will be hurt by additional cache misses due to creation of temporary arrays.

However, cache misses don't play such a big role as the calculation of `tanh`:

```
%timeit func1a(data, 0.5, 2.5, 2.5)  # 91.5 ms ± 2.88 ms per loop 
%timeit numpy.tanh(data)             # 76.1 ms ± 539 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

i.e. creation of temporary objects is responsible for around 20% of the running time.

---

FWIW, also for version with the handwritten loops, my numba version (0.50.1) is able to vectorize and call mkl/svml functionality. If for some other version this not happens - numba will fall back to gnu-math-library functionality, what seems to be happening on your machine.

---

Listing of `run.py`:

```py
import numpy

# TODO: define func1b for checking numba
def func1a(data, a, b, c):
    # pure numpy
    return a * (1 + numpy.tanh((data / b) - c))


data = numpy.random.randn(10_000, 300)

for _ in range(100):
    func1a(data, 0.5, 2.5, 2.5)
```

Answer (score 3):

### The performance difference is NOT in the evaluation of the tanh-function

I must disagree with @ead. Let's assume for the moment that

> the main performance difference is in the evaluation of the tanh-function

Then one would expect that running just `tanh` from `numpy` and `numba` with fast math would show that speed difference.

```
def func_a(data):
    return np.tanh(data)

@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def func_b(data):
    new_data = np.tanh(data)
    return new_data

data = np.random.randn(10_000, 300)
%timeit func_a(data)
%timeit func_b(data)
```

Yet on my machine the above code shows almost no difference in performance.

```
15.7 ms ± 129 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
15.8 ms ± 82 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

### Short detour on `NumExpr`

I tried a `NumExpr` version of your code. But before being amazed that it runts almost 7 times faster you should keep in mind that it uses all 10 cores available on my machine. After allowing `numba` to run in parallel too and optimising that a little bit the performance benefit is small but sill there `2.56 ms` vs `3.87 ms`. See code below.

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def func_a(data):
    new_data = a * (1 + np.tanh((data / b) - c))
    return new_data

@nb.njit(fastmath=True, parallel=True)
def func_b(data):
    new_data = a * (1 + np.tanh((data / b) - c))
    return new_data

@nb.njit(fastmath=True, parallel=True)
def func_c(data):
    for i in nb.prange(data.shape[0]):
        for j in range(data.shape[1]):
            data[i, j] = a * (1 + np.tanh((data[i, j] / b) - c)) 
    return data

def func_d(data):
    return ne.evaluate('a * (1 + tanh((data / b) - c))')

data = np.random.randn(10_000, 300)
%timeit func_a(data)
%timeit func_b(data)
%timeit func_c(data)
%timeit func_d(data)
```

```
17.4 ms ± 146 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
4.31 ms ± 193 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
3.87 ms ± 152 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.56 ms ± 104 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

### The actual explanation

The ~34% time that `NumExpr` saves compared to `numba` are nice but even nicer is that they have a concise explanation why they are faster than `numpy`. I am pretty sure that this applies to `numba` too.

From the [NumExpr github page](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr#how-numexpr-achieves-high-performance):

> The main reason why NumExpr achieves better performance than NumPy is
> that it avoids allocating memory for intermediate results. This
> results in better cache utilization and reduces memory access in
> general.

So

```
a * (1 + numpy.tanh((data / b) - c))
```

is slower because it does a lot of steps producing intermediate results.

Comment: Thanks for also comparing via `numexpr` @user2640045, I was unaware of this option. That being said my results do appear consistent with what @ead mentioned above, i.e. if I drop the use of `tanh` my functions 1b, 1c and 1d all show similar performance

Comment: @mgilbert Check my post again. I literally compared the `tanh` in `numpy` and `numba` and got the same result. But if his answer was correct the numba version should be way faster.

Comment: @user2640045 valid points. However, as you measurements show `numpy.tanh` takes 15.7 out of 17.4 ms. So the costs of temporary arrays isn't that big that could explain the difference. As I said, which version of tanh is used depends on python-distribution and versions used.

Comment: While numba uses svml, numexpr will use vml versions of `tanh` which probably explains the difference between numba and numexpr.

Comment: My guess is that you are on windows, where the tanh-implementation is faster as from gcc. Your numpy doesn't use vml, numba uses svml (which is not that much faster on windows) and numexpr uses vml and thus is the fastest.